# Saving file with the same name

Tags: c#

I have used this to save my file

```
string m_strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
m_strDate = m_strDate.Replace("/", "");
strPath += "/FileHeader_" + m_strDate + ".txt";
```

So as per this I can save a file per day. But if I create for another time the data in that text file is getting replaced by the new one. Now what I need is I would like to save my file with some name along with date and a number like

```
"/FileHeader_1" + m_strDate + ".txt"
```

and so on.

Comment: If you don't need time, use `DateTime.Today.ToString()` - it's little bit faster

Comment: Also don't forget about `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to combine directory name and file name without worrying about slash in the middle, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string fileName = "/FileHeader_" + m_strDate + ".txt";
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
  int index = 1;
  fileName = "/FileHeader_" + index + m_strDate + ".txt";
  while (File.Exists(fileName))
    fileName = "/FileHeader_" + ++index + m_strDate + ".txt";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
strPath = "/FileHeader_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".txt";
```

or check if the file exists:

```
strPath = "/FileHeader_{0}" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".txt";
if ( File.Exists( string.format( strPath, "" ) ){
  int i = 1;
  while( File.Exists(string.format( strPath, i ) ){ i++ ; }
  strPath = string.Format(strPath, i);
}
else {
  strPath = string.format( strPath, "" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string head = Path.Combine(strPath, "FileHeader_");
string tail = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".txt";

int index = 1;
string fileName = head + tail;

while (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    fileName = head + index + tail;
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string AddToFileNameUniqueNumber(string fileFullPath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileFullPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileFullPath), "Path can't be null or empty.");
        }
        if (File.Exists(fileFullPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(fileFullPath), "The specified path does not lead to the file.");
        }

        string fileDirectoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileFullPath);
        string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileFullPath);
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileFullPath);

        string fullFileNameWithUniqueIndex = "";

        for (int i = 1; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            fullFileNameWithUniqueIndex = Path.Combine(fileDirectoryName, $"{fileNameWithoutExtension} ({i}){fileExtension}");
            if (!File.Exists(fullFileNameWithUniqueIndex))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return fullFileNameWithUniqueIndex;
    }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what exactly your code does, otherwise it will not be helpful to learn of your answer.